# Play video in asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to play a video from video path that I have in database. If I hardcode the value in the following method then I am able to play the video. But m not sure how to play it dynamically directly from the database.

```
    <object id="Object1" classid="clsid:6BF52A52-394A-11D3-B153-00C04F79FAA6">
                               <param name="url" value="C:\Users\3embed\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HeritageWeb\HeritageWeb\Videos\tum-ho.mp4" / >
                        <param name="http://" />
                        <param name="AutoStart" value="1" />
                        <param name="ShowControls" value="1" />
                        <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="1" />
                        <param name="ShowDisplay" value="1" />
                        <param name="stretchToFit" value="1" />
                        <embed autostart="0" filename="" height="379" 
                            pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/Downloads/Contents/MediaPlayer/" 
                            showcontrols="1" showdisplay="1" showstatusbar="1" 
                            src="C:\Users\3embed\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HeritageWeb\HeritageWeb\Videos\tum-ho.mp4" type="application/x-mplayer2" width="424"></embed>

</embed>
```

How can we modify " " get values from database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make these changes to your `<embed>` object add `runat="server"` to make it available to codebehind and give it an `ID="Video"`. Now you can change its attributes as per need.

```
<embed autostart="0" filename="" height="379" runat="server" ID="Video"
                                pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/Downloads/Contents/MediaPlayer/" 
                                showcontrols="1" showdisplay="1" showstatusbar="1" 
                                 type="application/x-mplayer2" width="424"></embed>
```

Set the src in codebehind like this.

```
 Video.Attributes.Add("src","C:\Users\3embed\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HeritageWeb\HeritageWeb\Videos\tum-ho.mp4");
```

Comment: It is working fine in IE. But, In Crome it says plugin not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Best would be to create a control out of yr object and add a property that You feed the path/url of the movie

Answer (score 0):

```
<object id="Object1" classid="clsid:6BF52A52-394A-11D3-B153-00C04F79FAA6">
                               <param name="url" value="<%=GetVideoFilePath()%>" / >
                        <param name="http://" />
                        <param name="AutoStart" value="1" />
                        <param name="ShowControls" value="1" />
                        <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="1" />
                        <param name="ShowDisplay" value="1" />
                        <param name="stretchToFit" value="1" />
                        <embed autostart="0" filename="" height="379" 
                            pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/Downloads/Contents/MediaPlayer/" 
                            showcontrols="1" showdisplay="1" showstatusbar="1" 
                            src="<%=GetVideoFilePath()" type="application/x-mplayer2" width="424"></embed>

</embed>
```

You have to create a method named GetVideoFilePath in your page code behind and do all your database related stuff there.

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, use a literal and populate the source from your DB.

```
Literal.text = "<object id=""Object1"" classid=""clsid:6BF52A52-394A-11D3-B153-00C04F79FAA6"">
                           <param name=""url"" value=""C:\Users\3embed\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\HeritageWeb\HeritageWeb\Videos\tum-ho.mp4"" / >
                    <param name=""http://"" />
                    <param name=""AutoStart"" value=""1"" />
                    <param name=""ShowControls" value=""1"" />
                    <param name=""ShowStatusBar" value=""1"" />
                    <param name=""ShowDisplay" value=""1"" />
                    <param name=""stretchToFit"" value=""1"" />
                    <embed autostart=""0"" filename="""" height=""379"" 
                            pluginspage=""http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/Downloads/Contents/MediaPlayer/"" 
                        showcontrols=""1"" showdisplay=""1"" showstatusbar=""1"" 
                        src=" & your path here & " type=""application/x-mplayer2"" width=""424""></embed>

</embed>"
```

Something like that (not been tested but you get the point.)